# Designing of a ribbon microphone (sort of) output transformer

Tags: transformer, impedance, inductance, impedance-matching, microphone

I'm currently working on an experimental string musical instrument. It isn't my invention though. The source of inspiration called Dvina has an unusual pickup system. It senses the current induced in a string itself vibrating in a magnetic field, almost identical to a ribbon microphone. To couple the string to an amplifier an impedance matching transformer is used (as well as in ribbon mics). I have never designed a transformers before. All I know is a general turn ratio rule for voltages, currents and impedance. Where to start from? How to find a proper core and calculate an absolute number of turns? What else must be taken into consideration? I suppose the inductance but I have no idea how it must relate to other parameters. The inputs are the desired voltage gain and the string resistance. The ribbon mic schematic is just for reference.

[image: ribbon mic schematic]

Comment: An electric guitar pickup has a string vibrating in a magnetic field and does not use a stepup transformer.

Comment: The use of a step-up transformer is from the days when electronic amplification would have been very difficult or impossible; I expect a modern ribbon microphone (if they're even still used with how cheap electrets are) would use a FET-based preamplifier.

Comment: So you didn't find a good OpAmp? Before you build a transformer you may try Triad Magnetics MET-23-T  or Hammond 107L. Connect your string to the secondary side and use primary as output. It's not what they are made for, but might match here.

Comment: In this design, the entire length of the string is going to form a large loop, likely to pick up EMI from power lines, etc. Are you sure this is better than a tried and true guitar pickup?